# nuxt3 Failed to load response data if the request is incorrect

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

the application is on nuxt3:"^3.8.1"

If the request to the server is successful, then in the response I see the data that I receive from the server.
If the request is not successful, I see the same error always, it is "failed to load response data no data found for resource with given identifier".
[image]

here's my wrapper for the requests:

```
export const useApiFetch = (
  url: string,
  options: any
): any => {
  debugger
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()
  const { accessToken } = storeToRefs(useAuthStore())

  options.baseURL = config.public.apiBaseUrl
  options.key = url

  return ofetch(url, {
    ...options,
    onRequest ({ request, response, options }) {
      options.headers = options.headers || {}
      if (accessToken.value) {
        options.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken.value}`
      }
    },
    onResponseError ({ request, response, options }) {
      console.log('is active')
      console.log(response)
    }
  })
}
```

Moreover, **onResponseError **does not work in this case either, if the request is invalid, onResponseError is simply ignored and does not display any error фnd I think the two problems are related.

onRequest works in any case.

I tried using useFetch instead of ofetch or $fetch.
I tried to solve the problem by adding cors.ts to server/middleware with the following content:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': '*', 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': '*'.
```

Comment: Can you check what is the http status code in your Network Tab when you see this response? Also, side comment here, but why are you using `ofetch` directly instead of [$fetch](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/dollarfetch)?

Comment: http status code 400-409;
I have tried using both ofetch and $fetch, selecting different variants, no result